# List of all default Garry's Mod models

Tags: garrys-mod

Is there a list of all Garrys' Mod models that don't require any extra games like CS:S installed? I want to use them in an addon. Is there either an online list or a directory where they are all stored?

I have googled for hours and haven't found anything.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got no answers in over a week so apparently there is no such list. The best thing I found were the configuration files for the sandbox-spawnlist. You can find them under
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\GarrysMod\garrysmod\settings\spawnlist`
It is a bit weird to go through all the files but there is nothing better.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to list then here, but sadly there's a character limit instead you can check them out here:

https://pastebin.com/XCsdTCqN

I made a steam guide with them also if you want that.
http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1318229982

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty late but where you see those tabs off to the left of the spawn menu, go into "browse" then "games" then look for the gmod folder, or you could look into the hl2 folder. Not to be confused wiht hl2 ep 1 and 2 content, which isn't default.